# Where will the newly created cms page with admin panel appear in magento files?

Tags: magento2, frontend, cms, cms-pages

i have to render a page depending upon the logging in customer. so I need to create two home pages basically. If i create a new cms page with admin panel then where it will appear in files because i got to put css,html etc and and insert products links in that page as well?

Comment: you want to display different home page for logged in and logged out customer?

Comment: It is something like this....If X type of customers signs in then render 1st home page else (Y type of customers signs in)  render 2nd home page.....

Comment: okay got it. i will upload answer in few minutes

Comment: Okay....Thanks.

Comment: Answer posted. check and let me know it's working for you or not

Comment: Thanks....I appreciate that....Now you are creating here two home pages i.e Homepage-A and HomePage-B...and  now we got to put content in these home pages....so how to put content ...so how to do this...Anyways i can do this through admin panel itself in its editor(inserting products, images, text etc) but how to do that in my editor(i am using visual studio code ) because that home pages should appear in magento folders then only i can do that programmaticaly right?

Comment: I have made the logic to how to render different home pages depending upon the type of customer logging in but i don't know how to put content on those home pages programmatically with my editor

Comment: why you want to put condition in your home page?. already your page is different for different customer

Comment: Not condition...Content....For my 1st home page...i will override module-theme/layout/default.xml file and i will put content here by editing this file by adding blocks and templates right?...So my question is how to do the samething for my second homepage ?.

Comment: you can add block in cms page this way : {{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml"}} and other way : Go to Content >> Elements >> Pages >> Edit Homepage >> Open Design Tab and
Add Content in  Layout Update XML - <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">

Comment: Sir one last question...the two homepages A,B which you made will that be created in Magento folder... if(yes) where will that be created if(no) then we have to edit the page in admin panel itself?

Comment: means you want to make two xml file for two homepage?. so you can add content in xml file insted of cms page? Am i right?

Comment: yes.......................but how to do that?

Comment: yes i m making another code for you wait i will upload in few minutes

Comment: thanks for your time....i really appreciate that...

Comment: Code updated check and let me know it's same as per your requirement.

Comment: Yes.....Thankyou so much....

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this module [Change-Homepage-Based-On-Condition](https://github.com/nareshrupareliya/Change-Homepage-Based-On-Condition) and put in `app/code` directory and install this module:

Change cms identifier as per your cms page indetifier in below file

> NR/Cms/Controller/Index/Index.php

**Eaxmple :**

In this example i have set deafult **Home Page - A** for **Guest Customer**

[image]

After Logged In display **Home Page - B** for Customer.

[image]

Hope this will help you!

**How to Make XML file for Different Homepage**

You need to create two xml file for  2 cms home pages

1. create `homepage-a.xml` file under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/homepage-a.xml

and use content below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="content-a" template="Magento_Theme::html/homepage/content-a.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

2. create `homepage-b.xml` file under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/page_layout/homepage-b.xml

and use content below :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="content-b" template="Magento_Theme::html/homepage/content-b.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Override `layouts.xml` file under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layouts.xml

and use content below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="1column">
        <label translate="true">1 column</label>
    </layout>
    <layout id="2columns-left">
        <label translate="true">2 columns with left bar</label>
    </layout>
    <layout id="2columns-right">
        <label translate="true">2 columns with right bar</label>
    </layout>
    <layout id="3columns">
        <label translate="true">3 columns</label>
    </layout>
     <layout id="homepage-a">
        <label translate="true">Home Page - A</label>
    </layout>
    <layout id="homepage-b">
        <label translate="true">Home Page - B</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

You need to also create two phtml file for 2 homepage

1. Create `content-a.phtml` file for `homepage-a` content under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/homepage/content-a.phtml

and use content below :

```
<?php echo "Homepage - A"; ?> //put code in this file for Homepage A as per your requirement
```

2. Create `content-b.phtml` file for `homepage-b` content under

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/homepage/content-b.phtml

and use content below :

```
<?php echo "Homepage - B"; ?> //put code in this file for Homepage B as per your requirement
```

Note : Flush cache

Now time to assign created xml file to our CMS page

1. Go to Content >> Elements >> Pages >> Edit Homepage A >> Open Design Tab and set Home Page - A to layout and Save Page
2. Go to Content >> Elements >> Pages >> Edit Homepage B >> Open Design Tab and set Home Page - B to layout and Save Page

Note : Flush cache again and check

Hope this will help you!